# Excel VBA: Keeping formulas written in macro in worksheet, so user can manually change formula in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, cell-formatting

I am using a Macro to generate a report. I take information from structures and with formulas calculate various numbers which populate cells in a worksheet. These worksheets are created in the Macro as well. What do I have to do to ensure that the formulas for calculating the numbers I populate in cells stay in the cell when a user clicks the cell? i.e. the user can decide to change the formula for a cell after the report is made.

Here is how I create the new cells in a function `createTS()`:

```
Function createTS(ByRef index As Integer, ByRef wBStruct As wBStruct, ByRef gcBStruct As gcBStruct) As Worksheet
    '1) set up worksheet

    Set createTS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(, ActiveSheet, 1, xlWorksheet)
    With createTS
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(.CodeName).Name = cnDic(index)
        .Name = wBStruct.wTumorCellLine & "_" & wBStruct.wTypeBlock(index).projNum & "(" & gcBStruct.typeName & ")"
    End With
'...lots of code...
'this is where I populate the cells in the worksheet'
'...lots of code...
End Function
```

Within the function I would likely copy the information from the structures into certain cells (these cells contain no formulas, but are the original number from which I calculate the values in other cells. In other words, the formulas in the other cells would only be referencing other cells, not structures created in the macro). The point being that if I can get the formulas to stay in the cell, they can only reference other cells? (my initial belief)

an example cell could look like:

```
createTS.Cells(10,x).Value = createTS.Cells(1,5).Value*100 ' x would be some integer
```

Where do I include code to ensure that ^ formula stays within `cell (10,x)` so the user can later change the formula if desired?

Based off what I want to do, is there a better way to do this?

On a side note, assuming I am correct in my assumption with only referencing other cells with the formula, could the formula include variables referencing non cells at all, like a constant (`x = 5.3445435` I would rather use x than `5.3445435` over and over again)? Could said variable be another cell? What are the possibilities?

*Please note the Macro will shut down after it is done generating the report.*

Thanks!

Comment: I can't figure out what you want to do. If the user changes (or attempts to change) the formula, do you want the sheet to recompute, or not? What should happen, exactly? Please give a really simple example. You seem to have multiple questions running through each other, and that tends to make for a "bad" (as in, hard to answer well) question on this site. If you have multiple problems, don't hesitate to ask multiple questions.

Comment: I apologize for the messy question, but What I am looking for is for the cell to look like this if you double click it `=A1*100` provided I input this: `(Given: x = 2, y = 100)  ws.Cells(1,x).value= ws.Cells(1,1).value*y` in the Macro which produces the sheet. If you change the formula, the sheet should recompute. However, the Macro which produced the sheet should not have to be running when this occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you entered:

```
ws.Cells(1,x).Formula="=" & ws.Cells(1,1).Address & "*" & y
```

You would actually build up the formula for the cell, not its value.

Regarding the "variable" setting for use in worksheet formulas, the easiest way is to have the value in a cell and then name the range. You can type the name in the "Name Box" that usually has the cell address (next to the formula bar), or do it under the ribbon Formulas > Name Manager.
If you had named cell `Z99` as `x` then your worksheet functions can just reference this by name (e.g. `=A1*x`)

Comment: If I did this, could I reference the value of a cell in a formula where that cell which I am referencing was a cell that I previously built a formula for and not the value? At what point does the worksheet actually compute the formulas? Also, on that note, could I create a graph from "values" in cells which are composed of the "Formulas" I built in the cells?

Comment: Yes, you can reference a cell that has a formula not just a value. Excel keeps track of the cell dependencies (on the Formulas Ribbon - Formula Auditing > Trace Dependents or Trace Precedents). When a cell changes, all the Dependent cells will be recalculated and then their Dependents and so on. Charts are also dependent on their cells, so they are "recalculated" if the cell values change.

Answer (score 0):

Keep user input in one sheet, and formulas and business logic in a different sheet. The former is user editable (i.e. unlocked), whereas the second is locked and preferrably hidden. I wouldn't go as far as using a password, because sometimes the user knows best what he wants -- 2 years from now, you might be working in a different company and someone might want to change your formulas. It wouldn't hurt to make the sheet "Very Hidden" instead of just hidden.

If you absolutely must mix formulas and inputs in the same sheet, use locked/unlocked cells to force the user to keep things as is. Another alternative is using data validation to make sure the formula in the cell is the same as it was supposed to be -- perhaps saving the "correct" formula as a Named Range and checking against that.